# Native library path in gradle test

Tags: java, gradle

I'm using OpenCV in my Kotlin Gradle project, and I can't find out how to add native library path from command line when I'm running test:

```
./gradlew -Djava.library.path="/usr/local/share/java/opencv4/" test --stacktrace
```

And the test fails:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java452 in java.library.path: /Users/user/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
```

How to pass this path properly?

Note: I can't set this path in the `build.gradle` file as it's system-depended — I use macOS, CI uses Linux, etc, so it should be set via the command line or ENV.

Comment: I think I saw something weird about Gradle where someone was saying it's `-P` not `-D`. Try it and let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the Gradle documentation, you can configure `java.library.path` in a `systemProperty` in your `test` block and reference the property from there. Something like:

```
test {
    systemProperty "java.library.path" (findProperty("javaPath") ?: "")
}
```

and then invoke Gradle with `-PjavaPath="/usr/local/share/java/opencv4/"`